# Custom adapter not displaying output

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been battling with a simple applying a custom adapter to a listview for a few days now, hopefully, someone can help me where I'm going wrong.

I have a ListView (listViewAsItHappens) and I want to use a custom adapter to the view so I can format the look of the ListView. I have read lots of articles but none seem to appear to work as expected.

When I debug the code, it steps to the adapter but there's nothing displayed in the ListView. I'm getting no errors and it looks like all variables/objects are passing along nicely.

Any help in helping me getting the ListView to display the 3 lines of text and images will be great.

```
ListView list;
String[] itemname ={
        "Whistle",
        "Football",
        "Card"
};

Integer[] imgid={
        R.drawable.ic_whistle,
        R.drawable.ic_football,
        R.drawable.ic_yellowcard
};

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_refscorecard, container, false);
    list=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewAsItHappens);
    asItHappened adapter=new asItHappened(getActivity(), itemname, imgid);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My custom adapter (asithappens_listview is my XML layout);

```
public class asItHappened extends ArrayAdapter<asItHappened_List> {
private Activity context;
private String[] eventType;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public asItHappened(Context context, String[] event, Integer[] icon) {
    super(context, R.layout.asithappens_listview);
    this.eventType=event;
    this.imgid=icon;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.asithappens_listview, null,true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtEvent);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgEvent);
    rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtTitle.setText(eventType[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
   return rowView;
  }
}
```

Comment: you must override  getCount() methode and pass it eventType.lenght

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't overridden the `getCount()` method of the `ArrayAdapter`. You need to override it in your customer adapter class and return the size of elements that need to be displayed. Add something like this in your custom adapter class.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imgid.length;
    }
```

you could change the declaration of your custom adapter and extend from `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Or to have more flexibility you can extend it from `BaseAdapter` like this, just change your custom adapter class to this.

```
public class asItHappened extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity context;
    private String[] eventType;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public asItHappened(Context context, String[] event, Integer[] icon) {
        this.context = context;
        this.eventType=event;
        this.imgid=icon;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return eventType.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.asithappens_listview, null,true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtEvent);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgEvent);
        rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtTitle.setText(eventType[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked great, just had to change the reference to this.context = context; to this.context = (Activity) context;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `super constructor` where you need to pass the `string[]` on which basis it will trigger `getView` method for each `item` in `string[]` as in

```
public class asItHappened extends ArrayAdapter<String> { //< make it string
private Activity context;
private String[] eventType;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public asItHappened(Context context, String[] event, Integer[] icon) {
    super(context, R.layout.asithappens_listview,event); //<-- pass event
    this.eventType=event;
    this.imgid=icon;
}
//rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an Override method

**Add this**

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return eventType.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the adapter but you have not added objects into it. You might want to `add()` (method of adapter) the objects into the adapter so that the count gets updated.

Alternatively you will have to implement the `getCount()` method and maybe the `getItemId()` and `getItem()` method too.

Answer (score 0):

override the getcount method and return the size of array